# Element not being created and inserted with values

Tags: javascript, html

```
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
var split1 = input.split(";");
var split2 = input.split(":");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

if (split2[0] === "draw") {
  var thing = document.createElement("div");
  thing.style.backgroundColor = split2[1];
  thing.style.height = split2[2];
  thing.style.width = split2[3];
  thing.appendChild(canvas);
}
```

So I am trying to have an element created with custom values in an input box, why is it that everything is defined, but it does not work? this is what I type in (the input box value): "word(colon)lol(colon)red(colon)sans-serif"

Comment: You're telling it to only do something whenever the first word is `draw`. Typing in `word` won't make it do that. Besides, are you listening to an event like `change` or `input` to call this code?

Comment: No to call the code it’s a button to run it all but I’ll try changing up a few things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made some changes with your code and added a test for it, you can run :
"draw:red:100:200" - and check what you need .

You can see I changed the line :

```
canvas.appendChild(thing);
```

because you want to append to "canvas" , you tried to add the canvas to the new element you created right before.

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<script>
  function testClick() {
    const input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    const split2 = input.split(":");
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    if (split2[0] === "draw") {
      var thing = document.createElement("div");
      thing.style.backgroundColor = split2[1];
      thing.style.height = `${split2[2]}px`;
      thing.style.width = `${split2[3]}px`;
      canvas.appendChild(thing);
    }
  }
</script>
<button onclick="testClick()">test</button>

<div id="canvas"></div>
```

stackblitz : https://js-lwpolg.stackblitz.io

[Working example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQmfY.png)

Comment: Hi Medinios and welcome to SO. Did you know you can create *stack-snippets* to create runnable code here on the page? Look for the `<>` icon in the edit menu. Links to external pages can break or be removed, so it's best to keep everything on-site, unless it's not possible otherwise.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thanks for the tip!, I will use it :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;

var split2 = input.split(":");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");


if (split2[0] === "draw") {
  var thing = document.createElement("div");
  
  //var textnode = document.createTextNode("xxx");
  //thing.appendChild(textnode);
  thing.style.backgroundColor = split2[1];
  thing.style.height = split2[2];
  thing.style.width = split2[3];
  canvas.append(thing);  //canvas.appendChild(thing)
  
 }
```

```html
<input id='input' value='draw:red:15px:30px'>
<div id='canvas'></div>
```